# Potentiometer protection circuitry

Tags: potentiometer

My question arose from my previous question about a wind direction measuring circuit.
Please have a look at the manual: http://www.fondriest.com/pdf/rm_young_05103_manual.pdf
And here is the figures about my questions:
[image]

In Figure A, the potentiometer is used to output voltage proportional to the wind vane rotation angle.

In Figure B, the potentiometer comes to an end at point 1 and causes a short between the lines WHT(wind excitation voltage) and GRN(wind direction signal). But in theory current flows from + to ground. Do you think there is a path for current to flow in Figure B?

In Figure C, it seems like the situation is safe. Although the lines GRN and BLK are shorted at point 2, there is no potential difference and no current flows. Is that right?

My real confusion is about D6 and D7 the transzorb diodes(zener clampers?). I couldn’t really figure out in which circumstances they function and what happens in the absence of them. Why do we really need them?

In the manual it states: “To prevent false readings, signal conditioning electronics should clamp the signal to excitation or reference level when this occurs.” Do you think one needs an extra circuitry at the output?

Comment: It seems you need to learn what a potentiometer is and how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The transzorbs are there to protect your electronics from induced voltages on the cables. You could have very long outdoor cables from your electronics to the wind vane. Without some kind of protection the electronics would be wiped out during the next thunderstorm.

As to your second question, you left out the sentence before the one you quote. We don't know what the phrase "when this occurs" is referring to. However, adding some kind of input protection is good idea whenever you connect a long cable to sensitive electronics.

Comment: In Figure B, the potentiometer comes to an end at point 1 and causes a short between the lines WHT(wind excitation voltage) and GRN(wind direction signal). But in theory current flows from + to ground. Do you think there is a path for current to flow in Figure B?

Comment: you wrote "from induced voltages on the cables". how can this happen could you be more explicit? lightning?

Comment: Yes, it is lightning that would be the biggest threat. In such an event you can no longer assume that the far end of the cables are positive with respect to ground...the noise pulse could induce a positive or negative voltage on any wire.

Comment: what about my question: "In Figure B, the potentiometer comes to an end at point 1 and causes a short between the lines WHT(wind excitation voltage) and GRN(wind direction signal). But in theory current flows from + to ground. Do you think there is a path for current to flow in Figure B?"

Comment: Yes. When you have a long cable you can't rely on the "ideal wire" model anymore...there is significant resistance and inductance in series with each wire, and significant capacitance between wires. Shorting the wires at the far end doesn't create a solid connection to ground. When lightning strikes nearby, current flows **everywhere**.